# Doctrine querybuilder DATE_FORMAT not working

Tags: php, mysql, date, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm having some problems with DATE_FORMAT inside a createQueryBuilder

My code:

```
$qb7Days = $repo->createQueryBuilder('R')
        ->select( 'R.createdAt' )
        ->where( "DATE_FORMAT(R.createdAt, '%Y-%m-%d') = :afterDays" )
        ->andWhere( 'R.cCurrentReviewState = :state' )
        ->andWhere( 'R.reminder = :reminder' )
        ->setParameter( 'afterDays', $after7Days )
        ->setParameter( 'state',  $oReviewStateNotVerified ) // not_verified
        ->setParameter( 'reminder',  0 ) // never sent any reminder
        ->orderBy( 'R.id', 'ASC' )
        ->getQuery();
```

But im getting

```
 [Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]                                              
 [Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected known function, got 'DATE_FORMAT'
```

I've searched some links and find some explain that it should work this way, but for me it looks like im doing something wrong.

http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/labs/using-mysqls-date_format-in-doctrine-2-0/

Comment: Yes it perfect one. It working in simple query

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`DATE_FORMAT` along with a bunch of Mysql function are not directly available in Doctrine.

To use them you can either create your own or add an extension like [`beberlei/DoctrineExtensions`](https://packagist.org/packages/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) and then add the respective function to your doctrine bundle config like

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        ....
    orm:
        ....
        dql:
            string_functions:
                DATE_FORMAT: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\DateFormat
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just follow the tutorial in http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/labs/using-mysqls-date_format-in-doctrine-2-0/ and works awesome :)

Comment: I did it like this: after adding DoctrineExtensions to my vendor modules, added `$config->addCustomStringFunction('DATE_FORMAT', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\DateFormat');` to my _EntityManager_ Factory. Here `$config` is the instance of _Doctrine\ORM\Configuration_ to pass as the second parameter of _EntityManager::create()_.

Comment: I love Doctrine Entities but I **hate** Doctrine query builder! grr#@!

Comment: Thanks.. Its working.
You can specify as above globally or can use as below at file level (not to load above config everytime)

`$doctrineConfig = $this->_em->getConfiguration();
$doctrineConfig->addCustomStringFunction('DATE', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Date');`

Answer (score 7):

## Symfony 5 answer

Run

```sh
composer require beberlei/doctrineextensions
```

Add in

> config/packages/doctrine.yaml

```yaml
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            datetime_functions:
                DATE_FORMAT: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\DateFormat
```

The same goes for other *datetime* functions:

```yaml
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            datetime_functions:
                DATE_FORMAT: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\DateFormat
                DAY: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day
                MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
                YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
```

Answer (score 2):

DATE_FORMAT is not string function, its date_function:

> config.yml

```
doctrine:
     orm:
         dql:
             datetime_functions:
                 date_format: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\DateFormat
```

Answer (score 1):

DATE_FORMAT is not a doctrine recognised function. That link that you pasted is custom code the author wrote for him to get date_formate. You can write custom functions in doctrine and register them , neat ey ?

Here is an example of how to do that - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html

Option 1: You write that custom function for DATE_FORMAT so that you can use it again and again. 
Option 2: Maybe reformat the date in PHP to match the date format in the database , kinda like

> $after7Days->format('Y-m-d');

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this is correct for me only:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                ...
                dql:
                    datetime_functions:
                        DATE_FORMAT: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\DateFormat
```