# Conditional Object Query with Doctrine and Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am am trying to select a conditional statement (if $email isset & if $dateFrom isset) - without these conditions, my query works.

Likewise, if the query is not object oriented, the query works.

This works:

> ```
>    $q = $this->em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder('e')
>         ->select('subject, date_modified')
>         ->from('emails', 'e');
>     $results = $q->execute()->fetchAll();
> ```
>
> Returns all rows in the database.

This does not work:

> ```
>    $q = $this->em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder('e')
>         ->select('subject, date_modified')
>         ->from('emails', 'e');
>     if ($dateFrom){
>             $dt = new DateTimeHelper($fromDate);
>         $q->andWhere(
>             $q->expr()->gte('e.date_modified', $q->expr()->literal($dt->toUtcString()))
>         );
>      }
>     $results = $q->execute()->fetchAll();
> ```
>
> No error, it just doesn't return any results.

This does not work:

> ```
>    $q = $this->em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder('e')
>         ->select('subject, date_modified, (CASE WHEN '.$fromDate.' IS NOT NULL THEN e.date_modified LIKE '.$fromDate.'%')
>         ->from('emails', 'e');
>     }
>     $results = $q->execute()->fetchAll();
> ```
>
> Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string"

This:

```
         $q = $this->em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->select('subject, date_modified')
        ->from('emails', 'e')
        //if ($fromDate !== null) {
            ->where('e.date_modified = :fromDate')
            ->setParameter('fromDate', $fromDate);
        //}
    }
```

> PHP Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

This kind of works...?

```
         $q = $this->em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->select('subject, date_modified')
        ->from('emails', 'e')
        //if ($fromDate !== null) {
            ->where('e.date_modified = :fromDate')
            ->setParameter('fromDate', $fromDate->format('Y-m-d'));
        //}
    }
```

> Yields no error, but no data is returned.  Thinking the issue might be due to the date syntax; ->setParameter('fromDate', $fromDate->format('Y-m-d%')); doesn't work (the date is stored as: 2016-11-28 16:27:17) --any way to do a LIKE statement with this date query?

Tried the following without luck:

```
            ->where('e.date_modified LIKE :fromDate')
            ->setParameter('fromDate', $fromDate->format('Y-m-d%'));
```

Can anyone offer suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It should take a normal DateTime object as a parameter. `->where('e.date_modified = :fromDate')->setParamter('fromDate', $fromDate);` Note that $fromDate should be a DateTime object. I'd pass $fromDate to the repository as a DateTime object instead of a string, makes the repository method smaller and allows you to type hint the parameter.

Comment: Thanks! Now I get **PHP Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string - in file /vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php - at line 67 [] []** and line 67 is: `return parent::bindValue($param, $value, $type);`

Comment: Is the `date_modified` field from email entity a `datetime` type column?

Comment: Yes it is; date_modified is type datetime

Comment: Please show your `emails` Entity code.

Comment: Probably You compare datetime which format is Y-m-d H:i:s with Y-m-d (is time there), eg. '2016-11-29 20:32:16' != '2016-11-29'. In this case field 'date_modified' should be 'date' type, not 'datetime' or in query You can use DATE_FORMAT eg. ->where( "DATE_FORMAT(e.date_modified,  '%Y-%m-%d') = :fromDate" ). In order to use DATE_FORMAT - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298175/doctrine-querybuilder-date-format-not-working