# How to use DATE_FORMAT in MS-SQL using DQL/Query Builder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I am using doctrine 2.6, Symfony 3.4, MS-SQL. Using query builder I am getting date column as DateTime object from query builder but I need my column in "y-m-d" format. I tried [Doctrine querybuilder DATE_FORMAT not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298175/doctrine-querybuilder-date-format-not-working)
But it is in no help. My query builder looks like 
`

```
             $result
            ->select("DATE_FORMAT(p.createdAt, '%Y-%m-%d')")
            ->innerJoin('p.storeid', 'o')
            ->innerJoin('p.warehouseid', 'r')
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();`
```

Any Help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
select CONVERT(varchar(12),getdate(),105)
```

[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Query

```
    SELECT FORMAT(p.createdAt, '%Y-%m-%d')

FROM YourTable 

SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'MM.dd.yy') as date
```

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2655/format-sql-server-dates-with-format-function/

**UPDATE** : should be something like this in your case

```
$results = DB::table('YOUR_TABLE as p')
     ->where('p.id',$id)
     ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(p.createdAt, "%Y-%m-%d") as formatted_date')
     ->first();
echo $results->formatted_date->format('d-m-Y');
```

**OR Like this :**

```
$results = DB::table('Your_Table as p')
    ->where('p.id',$id)
    ->select("p.*","p.p_date as dob")
    ->first();
echo $results->dob->format('d-m-Y');
```

You need to set parameters for queryBuilder like this :

```
->setParameter('date', $symfonyDateTime->format('Y-m-d'));
```

SEE HERE:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Laravel gives an opportunity to define accessors/mutators. 
Which you can use in this case rather than to do it via Queries.
allmost same as Symfony you could try something like that is well.

HERE [Accessors & Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

method in Customer model class

```
public function getCustDobAttribute($value) {
    return //Format the value Which represent the value in database;
}
```

Comment: How can we use this in the query builder? According to your answer, I applied like  -**->select("FORMAT(p.createdAt, '%Y-%m-%d')")** ,but it does n't seems to work

Comment: @prabhatkumarjena See Updated answer