# Date can't be formatted into String from Querybuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I use the Querybuilder in Symfony 5 and have two date columns. In the JSON String the date would be not only one string. And I had tryied to add DATE_FORMAT to the select, but it would not work.

My current code is:

```
public function getTutoriallist(ManagerRegistry $doctrine, SerializerInterface $serializer): Response
{
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setCharset('UTF-8');
    $response->setEncodingOptions(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    
    $query = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('App:GrindingappTutorials')
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select(['t.id', 't.headline', 't.descriptiontext'])
        ->addSelect(['t.adddate'])
        ->addSelect(['t.changedate'])
        ->getQuery();
    $response->setData($query->getArrayResult());
    return $response;
}
```

and the JSON-Response looks like

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "headline": "How to messure the T8",
    "descriptiontext": "Learn how to messure the T8",
    "adddate": {
        "date": "2022-03-02 00:00:00.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
    },
    "changedate": {
        "date": "2022-03-02 00:00:00.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
    }
}
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63100066/151097

Answer (score 0):

`DATE_FORMAT` is not natively available in Doctrine. However you could write a custom dql function that does the job or simply use an existing available Doctrine extension such as [this one](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) as shown in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64739140/4724458). Be careful that the author use Mysql in his example.

Answer (score 0):

To get a RFC3339 formatted date you need to use the Serializer component [`DateTimeNormalizer`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#built-in-normalizers). This is usually loaded automatically.

However, by instancing a `JsonResponse` directly and using [`setData`](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/34e89bc147633c0f9dd6caaaf56da3b806a21465/JsonResponse.php#L155), you are using php's `json_encode` and not the Symfony Serializer. Use [`AbstractController::json`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/757d62bb4cc122024ac33cc6a82fce2360b9cb33/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/AbstractController.php#L142) instead and it should work as expected.

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()
// Conditions ommited
;

return $this->json($query->getResult());
```